# How can I show two parameters in laravel api if they both match in the same row in the database

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

in my database I have `$merchant_key` and `$reference_key`, both are not primary keys.

I would like to return these if they match in the same row in JSON from my database. I tried a couple of ways but it shows the data even if the second parameter is wrong `$reference_key`. So if `$merchant_key` is correct and `$reference_key` is wrong it still shows.

This is my API route

```
Route::get('Exttransfer/{reference}/{merchant_key}', 'UserController@show');
```

And The Function in Controller

```
public function show($reference,$merchant_key)
{
    return Exttransfer::where('reference',$reference)->get();
    return Exttransfer::where('merchant_key',$merchant_key)->get();
    

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a simply like below

```
return Exttransfer::where('reference',$reference)->where('merchant_key',$merchant_key)->get();
```

you can add more where query as many as you want, check more query method
[here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)